# Well posed Klein-Gordon equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I am interested in what are the largest families of initial conditions of the problem (in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$)
\begin{equation}\label{kg}
 \left\lbrace
 \begin{array}{ll}
  (\square+m^2)F(x)=0\\
  F(0,\vec{x})=g(\vec{x}) \\
  \frac{\partial F}{\partial x^{0}}(0,\vec{x})=f(\vec{x})
 \end{array}
 \right.
\end{equation}
I cut find something like "In order to this diferential equation be well posed, $g$ must live in $H^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$ and $f\in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$" on the web, but no for my equation.

So my question is ¿what are sufficent conditions over $f$ and $g$ in order to the probem be well posed?¿And is there any relation between this conditions and some Sobolev space?

I know probably the answer is in some classical book but I can find it.

Many thanks in advance.